# Creating SQL Table layout for dynamic document

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I apologize if this question is vague, but I'll try to be as clear as possible. I've been given a task where I'm to take a text file, store its content in SQL Server 2008, and automate the creation of a form letter given certain inputs. I've been able to break it into the following generic structure (*pay no attention to the content, it's just generic text, but the situational break-down is similar*):

```
Welcome [User],

[if @purchase = true, add this paragraph]
Thank you for purchasing the [device / subscription / subscription and device] 
from this business on [date].

[@purchase = true and @return = true, add this paragraph]
I'm sorry you returned it!

...

Signed, 
[Author]
[Author Image]
```

Assuming I'm already able to bring in all the necessary variables (user, purchase, return, date, device or device and subscription or subscription only), how should I go about storing the letter pieces in SQL? would it be considered fine to have a structure like the following:

```
+-------+-----------------+----------+--------+
| Order |      Text       | purchase | return |
+-------+-----------------+----------+--------+
|     1 | (1st paragraph) | TRUE     | null   |
|     2 | (2nd paragraph) | TRUE     | FALSE  |
+-------+-----------------+----------+--------+
```

Where I store the contents of the first paragraph as:

```
Thank you for purchasing the [device / subscription / subscription and device] 
from this business on [date].
```

And then write a stored procedure to piece it together based on the Boolean columns, and find/Replace the bracketed bits with input variables to output the entire letter as a string? It doesn't seem like it would be able to handle much variability, to be honest. Maybe breaking down the document into paragraph and sentence tables?

My ultimate goal would be to output this to either a report I create or, perhaps more ideally, to a Word document (though this is probably a whole different bit of research). Am I way off base here? Any insight is helpful.

Comment: do you want to return the hole string (doc) from storeprocdure?

Comment: Have a look into SQL Reporting Services

Comment: Sathish - That was the original idea, but I'm open to other ideas. Given this type of task, am I even in the territory of a correct approach?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is way to borad.

Answer (score 0):

you can use replace in select statment
for example

```
SELECT replace(replace(Text, 'device', @deviceVaribale), 'subscription', @subscriptionVaribale) FROM Order
```